# Find last element of if inside for loop PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP code to loop numbers from 5 to 41 with if condition inside. I want to detect the last element in if condition not in the whole loop.

This is my code

```
for($i=5;$i<=41;$i++){
    $true[$i] = $Class->isTrue($i); // The class return TRUE OR FALSE
    if($true[$i]{
        echo '<hr>'; // Print thematic break if not the last element 
    }
}
```

Comment: [end()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_end.asp) function returns last element in array

Comment: create variable outside the for loop and add the newly created variable inside if statement. The last true condition will always capture in the new variable you created.

Comment: @Gabriel I want to capture the last only.

Comment: you have to learn how variable works. Variable value are always replace by the latest value if you use the variable inside loop. first loop $var = 1 if condition true, 2nd loop if condition is false $var = 1 (still unchange), 3rd loop if condition true $var = 3 and so on.

Comment: If you want to print a delimiter between elements its easier to detect if its the first element, and just reverse the order of printing content vs delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (notice x != 0)

```
    for($i=5,$x=0;$i<=41;$i++){
        $true[$i] = $Class->isTrue($i); // The class return TRUE OR FALSE
        if($true[$i]{
            if($x != 0){ echo '<hr>'; }
            x++;
            // Print element here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution I think for my problem, instead of trying to catch the last element, I catch the first one then print the thematic break above all but the first element. so like this I don't print it below the last element as I want to do.

My code

```
for($i=5,$x=0;$i<=41;$i++){
    $true[$i] = $Class->isTrue($i); // The class return TRUE OR FALSE
    if($true[$i]{
        if($x == 0){ echo '<hr>'; }
        x++;
    }
}
```